# Regular Expression for Same Consecutive Numbers

Tags: regex

How do i write a regex to handle all instances where a the substring is 6 or more consecutive numbers such as this?

```
000000
111111
222222
333333
444444
555555
```

I tried `[0-9]{6,}`.

I plan to negative this afterwards so I can nullify strings with these cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `^([0-9])\1{5,}$`. Could you explain a bit the *I plan to negative this afterwards so I can nullify strings with these cases* part?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the part `\1` in the regex is new to me, if you dont mind can you share some knowledge on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match strings only consisting of 6 or more *identical* digits, you may use

```
^([0-9])\1{5,}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9])` - Capturing group 1 matching a digit
- `\1{5,}`  - 5 or more occurrences (due to the [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{5,}`) of the value captured into Group 1 (where `\1` is a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to Group 1 value)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Works just like what I needed! Thank you very much!