# Regular expression to find 3 consecutive numbers in a string equal to or increasing by 1 in Swift

Tags: swift

I am writing a code that takes a string and verifies it. First, we created a regular expression that has a string length of 5 or more and less than 24 and can use only upper and lower case letters and dashes, and first verified.

```
func iDValidator(_ id: String) -> Bool {
        let lengthAndElementRegEx = "^\\w{5,23}[a-zA-Z0-9-]$"
        let continuousRegEx = "I Need!!!"

        let lengthAndElementValidate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", lengthAndElementRegEx)
        
        guard lengthAndElementValidate.evaluate(with: id) == true else {
            return false
        }
        
        let continuousValidate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", continuousRegEx)

        guard continuousValidate.evaluate(with: id) == true else {
            print("###false")
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

After that, I would like to verify that a number appears 3 times in a row or 3 consecutive numbers in a string such as "111", "222", "123", and "456". Do you have a simple regex? Help!

Comment: Maybe you can try to check without using a regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
([0-9])\1{2}|(012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)
```

Where:

- `([0-9])` - Group 1 capturing 1 digit
- `\1{2}`  - Captures 2 more occurrences (due to the [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2}`) of the value captured in Group 1 (where `\1` is a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to Group 1 value)
- `(012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789)` - simply matches all possible number sequences

You can try it yourself: https://regex101.com/r/noBKsE/2

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001668/regular-expression-for-same-consecutive-numbers)